# Combining AWS cli commands with xargs not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, windows-10, aws-cli, git-bash, xargs

I want to have a one liner for setting properties to AWS Cloudwatch loggroups. I came across the xargs command. But I do not understand what am I doing wrong:

```sh
aws logs describe-log-groups \
--query "logGroups[*].logGroupName" \
--output text \ 
| xargs -I {} -n 1 \
 aws logs put-retention-policy \
--log-group-name {} \
--retention-in-days 14
```

As far as I understood `{}` takes the first command's output as list and pipes each element to the second command via xargs.

However, I result in this:

```sh
An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the PutRetentionPolicy operation: Member must have length less than or equal to 512
```

I am assuming that it passed the list to xargs, not just one element of the first command's output.

---

I am using Windows 10 with git bash

Comment: Remove space after "\".

Comment: Where exactly? And why?

Comment: Press `Ctrl`+`a` and take a look at your code. With this space `bash` splits your code in two parts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sh
aws logs describe-log-groups | \
 jq ".logGroups[].logGroupName" \
 |xargs -I {} -n 1  aws logs put-retention-policy \
  --log-group-name {} --retention-in-days 14
```

```sh
aws logs describe-log-groups \
--query "logGroups[].logGroupName" \
--output text \
| xargs -I {} -n 1 \
 aws logs put-retention-policy \
--log-group-name {} \
--retention-in-days 14
```

`OS` : `Mac OSX`

Comment: I do not understand why to use -p. This is not related to my question.

Comment: @WorkoutBuddy with both the commands I shared?  which os you are using? just asking in case the ```xargs``` differs across the OSes.

Comment: Yes, with both commands I have added  my OS in my question.

Comment: your first command ends up with:
' at 'logGroupName' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern: [\.\-_/#A-Za-z0-9]+ted: Value 'C:/Users/i016249/AppData/Local/Programs/Git/aws-glue/crawlers

Comment: @WorkoutBuddy I see you are using ```windows``` which you just updated in the question, that's the reason of failure and I am not sure which implementation ```windows``` uses.

Comment: @WorkoutBuddy I would suggest to move away from `xargs` syntax and use bash style for loop.  Because the ```windows``` implementation of ```xargs``` might not support all kinds of options which are supported in ```POSIX``` implementation.